# Add pagination at Featured Products on homepage (X-Cart)

Tags: pagination, x-cart

I am working with x-cart website, and I have one question about how can I add pagination to featured products on homepage? I want its process like that, if user clicks on next button, it will shows other featured products (in this case, it still stays on homepage). Is it possible?

I am waiting for your answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your template, but lets assume your Featured products are displayed this way:

```
<div id="products">
    <div class="product-item product-item-odd">...</div>
    <div class="product-item product-item-even">...</div>
    <div class="product-item product-item-odd">...</div>
    <div class="product-item product-item-even">...</div>
    ...
</div>
```

Than you can use jQuery (which is probably old in x-Cart) to paginate:

```
function paginate(container, max) {
    var items = container.children();
    var totalItems = items.length;
    var totalPages = Math.ceil(totalItems / max);
    var pager = $('<p class="my_pager"></p>');
    for (p = 1; p <= totalPages; p++) {
        pager.append('<span class="open_page">' + p + '</span>');
        items.slice((p - 1) * max, p * max).attr('data-page', p);
    };
    container.after(pager);
    $('.open_page').click(function (e) {
        $('.open_page').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        var pageToOpen = $(this).text();
        items.hide();
        items.filter('[data-page=' + pageToOpen + ']').show();
    });
    $('.open_page:first').click();
};
paginate($('#products'), 2);
```

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/zan09wr7/)